# fetch mysql data into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var events = [
        {"id":"1","title":"pending","start":"","end":"2020-04-27 10:25:34","url":"","allDay":"1"},
        {"id":"2","title":"22","start":"2013-12-15 10:25:47","end":"2013-12-16 10:25:39","url":"","allDay":"1"},
        {"id":"3","title":"33","start":"2013-12-26 10:25:50","end":"2013-12-27 10:25:42","url":"","allDay":"false"},
        {"id":"4","title":"2-12 ","start":"2020-04-20 10:26:28","end":"2020-04-20 10:26:28","url":"","allDay":"false"},
        {"id":"6","title":"test nay","start":"2013-12-09 00:00:00","end":"2013-12-11 00:00:00","url":"event","allDay":"false"}
        ]
```

i want to Retrieve data in my database into this JavaScript variable please anyone simply explain how do to do that ?

Comment: You'll need some backend service running on top of your DB. Easiest is probably to write it in node so you stick to javascript, look here https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp. Then you can fetch towards your service using for instance `fetch`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API. Here's a good enough tutorial: https://bezkoder.com/react-node-express-mysql/.

Comment: you may do two things, fist write an API in php/node/java etc and hit that from java script using ajax and then you get that data, second thing while loading the page load that data in some variable and set in html in some hidden field and from java script fetch from html. first method is better. Go through this link https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use any of the backend technologies (Java/Python/php/Node JS etc) to save the json array to DB. This is because javascript can not directly handle or connect to Database.

From javascript side, you can use jQuery ajax to send the data to your backend api as follow.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "post",
    url: "",            //your backend API endpoint
    data: {data: events},

    success: function(responseData){

        //If backend api runs successfully, control comes to this method with responseData as return from api
    },

    error: function(responseData){

        // If api call does not run properly, control comes in this method.
    }
});
```

And your backend API got the data, connects to the DB and run the SQL to store the data. So based on backend technology, you have to develop the code.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, create a get or post route which sends data in JSON format. 
On the client side, use jQuery/fetch/axios to grab that data. It's easy. Try this, https://github.com/axios/axios